# Can't access Azure Linux Virtual Machine via browser/HTTP

Tags: azure, http, virtual-machine

I have set up a VM in azure with Redhat Linux OS, I have installed Httpd service and placed a static webpage to access.

I am not able to access my VM via browser with public IP set on my VM. Although, I am able to ssh into the machine.

Steps I have already tried:

1. Set an inbound rule on the network security group for port 80, 443, 22(ssh).
2. Attached this NSG to both VNET & NIC but no luck.
3. Tried the same in AWS EC2 instance it works like a charm. Not sure why Azure is not that straight forward.
4. Tried to find the solution online and documentation but no luck.

Please help if you have any idea how can I access my app via a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Manu for your suggestion. But I found that Linux firewall was blocking it. So here is what I did:
Since I am using RHEL 8, the inbuilt firewall is via Firewalld not iptables(which is there for RHEL 6 and before).

1- By default, only port 22 open in firewalld. "firewall-cmd --list-all" command will show the details.
2- Added HTTP port. By using below 2 commands

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

3- Verify the change by using any of the below commands:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-services
$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-services --permanent
```

Please refer this link for more details:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-rhel-8/

Answer (score 0):

Please check, if SELINUX is configured correctly
Redhat reference here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_confined_services/chap-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server

Thanks,
Manu